# Rails: Ensure datetime uses system time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, timezone

In our rails app, the timezone is set to UTC in our environment file.  This doesn't cause any problems when running on our production or staging servers.  However, none of our local development machines are set to UTC in the system clock, and this is causing some test failures when comparing dates.  This is because Rails is using UTC when we call `DateTime.now`, where-as our MySQL database is using the system time (CST in my case).

Is there a way to ensure that in certain cases, `DateTime.now` does NOT use the UTC timezone?  I guess what I'm asking for is a pure SQL way of updating date fields, which bypasses the Rails engine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should be able to tell rails to use local settings only for `development` and other environments like `test` by adding this to corresponding `config/environments` file :

```
config.time_zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" #Change this
config.active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes = false
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

That worked for me, but I switched everything including production to local time. But I don;t see why this approach wouldn't work per environment!

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that our dev team is split up across different time zones, and we would have to figure out a way to keep git from overriding the environment file every time we committed.

Comment: Interesting ... I'd go with a file in config/initializers defining constants, that is in .gitignore. Not sure if you can access constants defined in an initializer from config/environment though ... depends on which are loaded first